# Installing application programmatically from Android source

Tags: android, android-intent, installation, apk, uninstallation

I use the following code to install an application, from my application which I have placed inside the android source code.

I have compiled and built an emulator, I can see my application working perfect inside the emulator built from Android source.

At a particular point in my application, I try to install another application from within my application. The APK path of the application I am trying to install is:

```
/data/data/com.games.golf/cache/MyGames/Golf.apk
```

Following is the code I use to install the application in the above path from my application:

```
    private void InstallApplicaiton(String url)
{
    PackageParser.Package mPackage = PackageUtil.getPackageInfo(Uri.parse(url));
    installingList.addView(getProgressView(mPackage,url));
    int installFlags = 0;
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(mPackage.packageName, 
                PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
        if(pi != null) {
            System.out.println("Inside pi if not null");
            installFlags |= PackageManager.INSTALL_REPLACE_EXISTING;
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String installerPackageName = getIntent().getStringExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME);
    System.out.println("installerPackageName:"+installerPackageName);
    PackageInstallObserver observer = new PackageInstallObserver();
    pm.installPackage(Uri.parse(url), observer, installFlags, installerPackageName);

}

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case INSTALL_COMPLETE:
                System.out.println("package installed");
                break;
        }
    }
};
class PackageInstallObserver extends IPackageInstallObserver.Stub {
    public void packageInstalled(String packageName, int returnCode) {
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(INSTALL_COMPLETE);
        msg.arg1 = returnCode;
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

I get SOP message inside the handler from `PackageInstallObserver` that the package is installed. But I am unable to see the installed application in launcher.

I am aware of the fact that, third party applications cannot install / uninstall APKs programmatically. For this reason, I have compiled and built an emulator by including my application, so that I can install another applications from my application. But here also when I get stumped with the code above, I am clueless of the reason.

I have used the same code which android uses for installing packages, but why the above code does not work and the package is not getting installed is what I am not able to understand.

The only problem I could notice here is that `String installerPackageName` is always null.

Any help in this regard which would help me resolve this issue , such that the package gets installed from my application, would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

Following is the log. Is it because that, I try to install this from emulator and that too from cache folder - `/data/data/com.games.golf/cache` . Has it got something to do with permission in accessing this folder?

```
05-29 19:31:57.237: W/asset(7490): Asset path     /data/data/com.games.golf/cache/MyGames/Golf.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=0).
05-29 19:31:57.237: W/DefContainer(7490): Failed to parse package
05-29 19:31:57.237: W/ActivityManager(79): No content provider found for permission revoke: /data/data/com.games.golf/cache/MyGames/Golf.apk
05-29 19:31:57.297: I/ActivityManager(79): Displayed com.games.golf/.screens.PackageInstaller: +448ms
05-29 19:31:57.607: D/dalvikvm(79): GC_EXPLICIT freed 71K, 11% free 8410K/9415K, paused 4ms+7ms
```

Comment: Try this -
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/data/data/com.games.golf/cache/MyGames/Golf.apk")),
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                                           
        context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: I have edited the code by including PackageInstallObserver code and the handler I use to track whether installation is completed.

Comment: Try moving the apk to another directory, maybe to the sd card and then installing it.